# Spring Roo project on Spring Tool Suite 3.5.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

I have installed Spring Tool Suite 3.5.0 (STS). I was expecting to be able to create a Spring Roo project within STS as have been possible in the past in previous versions of STS. The option Roo project isn't among the listed project types. How can I create a Roo project within STS?

Answer (score 3):

Though I wrote this matter in my blog in Japanese, I hope you can see the figures there and will find the solution.
http://nomprix.blogspot.jp/2014/04/sts-350spring-roo.html