# How to add Spring roo on Spring Tools Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I 've installed sts but the create a new roo project does not exists, what i have to do to add spring roo? In the previous version  i could create it but not in 3.5.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Roo project on Sprint Tool Suite 3.5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364056/spring-roo-project-on-sprint-tool-suite-3-5-0)

Answer (score 9):

In Spring tool suite, click on the Extensions link in the Dashboard. Search for Spring Roo and install it.

Comment: to be more carefully: Help -> Dashboard then go to Extensions tab -> find 'Roo' -> check and install: 'Spring Roo (current production release)' and 'Spring IDE - Roo Extension'.

Answer (score 3):

STS 3.5.0 doesn't include Spring Roo. You must install it manually using the STS Dashboard.