# No option to create Roo project is Spring Tool Suite (STS version 3.6.1)

Tags: eclipse, spring, project, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

There seems to be no option in STS 3.6.1 to create a Roo app. While Googling I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365784/how-to-add-spring-roo-on-spring-tools-suite) question for the same problem in version 3.5.0, and the sloution was to install Roo to STS manually as it is no longer included. Sweet, so I did that.

I installed it from the STS dashboard and after installation was complete and STS was re-started the dashboard shows this (so the installation was successful):

[image]

And lo and behold... still no option to creat a Spring Roo app!

[image]

So... how can I find the option to create a Spring Roo app from within Spring tool Suite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You must install "Spring IDE - Roo Extension" too:**

[image]

**Then "Create Roo Project" will be ready:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Help -> Install new software` And select *SpringSorce Update Site* to install Spring-Roo related features.

Anyway, you could run the *Spring Roo shell* on the *systems shell* to create the project (STS is great tool, but it isn't required to work with Roo).

Good luck!