# Cannot run Spring Roo solely from Windows command line as guided in the manual

Tags: installation, spring-roo

I'm new to Spring Roo and follow the manual in the downloaded package officially provided by springsource at http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

Though, I cannot run roo from Windows command line window. The error when I run `roo` from `cmd` window can be viewed [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2014/roo-errors.log).

Having [STS downloaded](http://spring.io/tools/sts), [installing Roo plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26058215/248616), creating a Spring Roo Project, starting Roo console will get me there.

So, my question is, the manual is outdated/incorrect for Windows OS or I missunderstand something here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jmvivo idea, we found the cause - imcompatible between `Java 8` and `Spring Roo 1.2.5 RELEASE`. The issue is officially known and report on Spring Roo Jira [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3496).

So make sure your `roo` is running `java.exe` from Java 7 or lower.

> java -version

Then you can call `roo` as guided.

p.s.

When editing %PATH% system variable, **make sure

1. You have `%JAVA_HOME` pointing to JDK 7
2. You put `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` on top** so that the java location you define in `%JAVA_HOME%` is applied.

Otherwise `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`, or `%SystemRoot%\system32` may have higher priority to your `%JAVA_HOME%`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the errors throws by Roo I can see that some system required packages are missing:

- javax.imageio
- javax.xml.namespace
- javax.xml.parsers

So, I think you're right: *the manual is outdated* and should remove *IBM Java* from supported JDK.

I you want, you could report it in [Spring-Roo Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO)

The workaround could be install a Oracle standard JDK.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm using Java 8 from Oracle though still recieving the error.

Comment: Java 8 is not supported yet: use Java 7. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3496

Comment: I found the issue. It's all about Java 8. Need to use Java 7 or lower.